# CSS Dropdown - Radius far left and right edges only

Tags: css

Hopefully this is an easy one for someone. I've built a CSS dropdown, and want to add a radius to round the corners of the whole menu. I've used:

```
border-radius: 0px;
```

...to add the radius, but I must have it in the wrong place, as it rounds each menu option instead. I've experimented with different locations, but can't figure out how to sort it.

I've put it in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Flamin_Squirrel/noxqn7z4/6/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zbwz0jxo/

Using the pseudo-classes first-child and last-child, like below:

```
.menu > ul >li:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.menu > ul >li:last-child {
  border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

This will allow you to only apply your border-radius to the first and last list items of the menu only.

For more info on the first-child and last-child pseudo classes check out MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child). That in combination with pseudo-classes such as [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) will give you more fine grain control over your CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Add this (and remove your existing border-radius rule):

```
.menu > ul > li:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px ;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/noxqn7z4/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should place the border-radius code inside of `.menu` since that is the element you want to have the rounded corners.